# How to listen to dragstart even in a tree panel in Extjs?

Tags: extjs

ExtJs Version: 6.2.1

As title, I've digging in the source code for awhile and haven't see any where I can drop in to listen to this even. Would be appreciated if anyone could point out or show some guide.

Comment: As per the documentation dragstart is not an event in Ext.Tree.Panel docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html DragStart is often use for slider.

Comment: Yes I did see that part in the doc. But what I wanted to know is if any where in the tree panel parts that I can drop a listener to dragstart event, that would be reall great. And actually, knowing how to listen to dragstart event in Extjs would be even better as it's existence in doc / source code is nearly 0.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive by listening to the dragstart event? It would be easier to answer your question if we knew what you are doing with it. There are plugins to make it easy to implement the more obvious actions of dragging/dropping on trees but I guess you have already discounted these: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#tree-two and also http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop.html

Comment: The problem with Tree Panel, and DragDrop by mouseevent in general, is that it triggers / causes weird behavior when you move the mouse over selectable text area. It causes the text to be selected.

So In order to avoid that, I could do `onmousedown` on the view and then add a class to make text unselectable, but `onmousedown` will never feels as good as `dragsstart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `plugins` in `viewConfig` of a tree panel, specifing `dragZone` with an object with method `onStartDrag` will allow you to hook in to internal drag process of Extjs.

This class doesn't not extend Observable so it's harder to find the right place to look for, as normally you would expect to `.fireEvent('startdrag')` instead.

You can't use component query to go up to find the right parent tree view / panel to signal the right event either, so it's best to create a callback by Extjs Function utilities

Edit: Or you can do something like this to dispatch `dragstart` event in the `treeview`:

```
dragZone: {
  onStartDrag: function(x, y) {
    this.view.fireEvent('dragstart', x, y);
  }
}
```